# Specify operation order in Spring generated WSDL

Tags: spring, soap, wsdl, spring-ws

We are using WSSpringServlet (Spring 4.10) for publishing an autogenerated WSDL, but it seems to generate different WSDL on each start-up. Is there a way to force any strict sorting? Even alphabetical would be good enough.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to maintain a consistent WSDL, when you generate dynamically. It's highly recommended to generate during development phase and use static in higher environments.
The Spring doc says same thing [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/reference/html/server.html).

Navigate to section 5.3.1.1. Automatic WSDL exposure --> Caution

Comment: It states that it might "change slightly" between Spring releases. What I observe is that it can changes even between deployments.

Comment: "change slightly" is the dynamic behavior of generating WSDL file. Spring has no control over that.